# How to Make Ionic 4 app open geo link or geo intent?

Tags: android, ios, angular, cordova, ionic-framework

I would like to make an ionic be able to open a location like Google Maps does.
In Android for example, when the user clicks a link such as

```
<a href="geo:37.786971,-122.399677" ></a>
```

The OS shows different apps that can handle location and do something with it.
I would like to make the ionic app offered as part of these options.
Then when the user selects the ionic app, getting access to that location obviously.

I know that this can be acheived by updating the AndroidManifest file but I was wondering if there is a plugin that does that for both iOS and Android.

Comment: Please Check: https://ionicframework.com/docs/native/deeplinks

Comment: My question is not about deeplinking which associates a web url to a deep page into the app. This is about making the app able to open a generic location intent